# controlling filename download selenium

Tags: selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
path_to_download = '/home/dev/'
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": path_to_download,
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})

options.add_argument('start-maximized')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/dev/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver',
    options=options)
#long logic
elem2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Excel')]")))
elem2.click() #downloads the file (export to excel)
```

for now I am stuck with putting a `time.sleep(5)` then `os.rename(f'{path_to_download}/exported.xlsx',f'{path_to_download}/{my_id}.xlsx')`

is there a way of controlling the filename while or before the file is downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by checking for the file existence in your download directory and loop over and over until the file appears.

You can do someting like that :

```
    # check the size of the file and return 0 if doesn't exist
    def getSize(filename):
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            st = os.stat(filename)
            return st.st_size
        else:
            return 0

    def wait_download(file_path):
        current_size = getSize(file_path)
        printed = False
        start_time = time.time()

        # loop over and over until the current_size change
        while current_size !=getSize(file_path) or getSize(file_path)==0:
            current_size = getSize(file_path)

            # print something to the string to know that we are waiting for the file
            while printed == False:
                print("Downloading file...")
                print("Waiting for download to complete...")
                printed = True



            # Here we add an exit to not loop forever
            if (time.time() - start_time) > 15:
                return -1

       return 0

# In your code you can call the function like that
files = wait_download(f'{path_to_download}/exported.xlsx')

if files == 0:
    #do something
else:
    # the file didn't download
```

Comment: I see, so the `wait_download` should be called after I initiate the download and wait for it till it returns 0 (meaning file fully downloaded)

Comment: Yes, you click to download and then you wait until the file download